# Unbalanced keys lead to performance problems in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cpu-usage, pyspark, distributed-computing

I have an issue where I have a set of keys, and a (larger) set of records that I want to aggregate across keys. The issue I have is that the number of records per key varies wildly. A single key can have millions of records that map to it, whereas plenty of the keys only have a 1-5 records that map to them. The end goal is to aggregate the values (stored in a list). Right now, this is what I am doing:

```
data = sc.textFile("my/path/to/file/*).map(lambda x: x.split(","))
kv = data.map(lambda x: (x[0],x[1:])
```

kv.take(4) looks like this:

`("key1", [1, 2, 3, 4]), ("key1", [1, 2, 3, 4]), ("key2", [1, 1, 1, 1]), ("key2", [0, 1, 0, 1])`

Right now, I am performing `kv.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)`. Then I perform an iterative addition method to yield the following output:
`("key1", [2, 4, 6, 8]), ("key2", [1, 2, 1, 2])`

However, I noticed that `reduceByKey` is taking extremely long. Given, it is a shuffle operation and these take time. But I'm also aware that the severe imbalance in the number of records per key could be causing less than ideal thread handling, since the records are not evenly distributed across keys.

Am I correct in thinking that the imbalance in records / key could be causing the slowdown? And what can I do to fix this? I've heard of salting mentioned in passing, but I'm not sure how to implement that.